# getting error ssh exception auth fail in jenkins while executing script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jsch

I configured in jenkins pre-build step--> Execute shell script on remote host using ssh

Before the build i want execute the below script
I am getting below error 
can anyone have idea and if any information i missed please let me know
Actually the below script is to stop the server
[EnvInject] - variables injected successfully

executing script
cd /home/appsusr; ./ims-carte-stop.sh

```
[ssh] Exception:Auth fail
com.jcraft.jsch.jschException: Auth fail
     at com.jcraft.jsch.session.connect(session.java.452)
     at com.jcraft.jsch.session.connect(session.java.150)
     at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHSite.createSession(SSHSite.java:114)
     at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHSite.executeCommand(SSHSite.java:124)
     at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHBuilder.perform(SSHBuilder.java.51)
     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$Runner.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java.19)
     at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java.700)
```

Comment: can any body please respond to this post

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this today. I could ssh from within Jenkins to two systems but not the third, all with shared credentials.  It turned out the /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the failing system had "PasswordAuthentication no". This caused the correctly reported Auth fail.

HTH

Comment: I wanted to use keyfile only auth so I turned this off. Looks like jenkins' ssh client needs this on for some reason. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and how I fixed it was to add a cmdline switch when starting up jenkins.  I set the (long winded) `-Dorg...useCLI=true`

```
nohup java -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.useCLI=true -jar jenkins.war > jenkins.log 2>&1 &
```

The gist of it is that this switch makes jenkins use installed git, not a JGit client.

Hope that helps.

Also, here's a URL to check out (especially long trail of comments)

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17204

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue after I changed the password of `Remote Linux machine`.

Updating **`Passphrase/Password`** in **`Credentials`** section of a Job as well as under **`Manage Jenkins -> Configure Sytem -> SSH remote hosts`** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may come from /run/nologin. /run/nologin is created by systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service. It is then removed by systemd-user-sessions.service.

So you have to delete this:

```
$ ls -l /run/nologin
# rm /run/nologin
```